# sqlalchemy - Data not persisting in database with session.commit()

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using PostGreSQL with sqlalchemy.  I am relatively new to databases, and brand new to sqlalchemy.  I currently have a simple database that contains columns for a githash (primary key), a committer, and a date.

I have a JSON file that has been gathering the data, and my main goal is to transfer all the data from the file to the database (and all new data will be placed into the database as well).  The python script that I have written allows for an argument (-j) and filepath to the json file to be passed in to be added to the database; however it isn't required since once the data is in the database, I want to be able to get data from the database without specifying a JSON file.

This is where my problem stems from.  When I specify a JSON file, as below:

```
python PostGreSQLTest.py -j JSONFile.json
1012
```

1012 rows are added, and then subsequently fetched, from the database, and the database GUI reflects this as well.

When, immediately afterwords, I call the script without the JSON file, and attempt to get the number of rows from the database, it shows 0 rows (both as output from the script, and within the GUI.)

```
python PostGreSQLTest.py
0
```

It seems as it the data is not persisting in the database between sessions, even though I do call session.commit().  I have included a sample of the code below.  Any insight into this matter would be much appreciated.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import json
import os

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Text, Integer, Date, create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())

class TestRecord(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test_table'
    githash = Column(Text, primary_key=True)
    committer = Column(Text)
    date = Column(Date)

class TestDatabase(object):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        self.db_name = "test_db"
        self.user = "un"
        self.pw = "pw"
        engine = self.__init_db()

    '''Initializers'''       
    def __init_db(self):
        engine_string = 'postgresql://{0}:{1}@localhost/{2}'.format(self.user, self.pw, self.db_name)
        engine = create_engine(engine_string, echo=False)
        session.remove()
        session.configure(bind=engine, autoflush=False, expire_on_commit=False)
        Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
        return engine

    def __grab_json_file(self, filename):
        jsonFile = open(filename, 'rb')
        J = json.load(jsonFile)
        jsonFile.close()
        return J

    '''Helper Functions'''

    '''Main Functions'''
    def add_entries_from_JSON(self, filename):
        '''
        Add Entries From JSON reads in a JSON file and creates records in the database.
        :param filename: <String> Full path to the JSON File
        :return success: <bool> True if records are successfully written, False otherwise
        '''
        TR_entries = []
        success = False
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            # If the JSON file exists, open it and create records
            entries = self.__grab_json_file(filename)
            for key in entries.keys():
                TR = TestRecord()
                TR.githash = entries[key]["gitHash"]
                TR.date = entries[key]["Date"]
                TR.committer = entries[key]["Committer"]       
                TR_entries.append(TR)
            # Add all records from the list of TestRecord objects to the database
            success = self.add_multiple_entries(TR_entries)
        else:
            print "JSON file '{0}' provided does not exist.".format(filename)
        return success    

    def add_multiple_entries(self, entries):
        '''
        Add multiple entries adds multiple entries to the database.
        :param entries: <list of TestRecord> list of records to add to the database
        :return success: <bool> True if successfully added, false otherwise
        '''
        success = True
        try:
            session.add_all(entries)
            session.commit()
        except:
            success = False
            raise
        return success

    def get_num_rows(self):
        '''
        Get the number of rows in the database.
        :return numRows: the number of rows in the database
        '''
        numRows = session.query(TestRecord).count()
        return numRows


    def cleanup(self):
        '''
        Cleanup wraps everything up.
        '''
        session.close()

def main (jsonFile=None):
    TD = TestDatabase()
    if jsonFile is not None:
        if TD.add_entries_from_JSON(jsonFile) is False:
            print "Failed to add entries from JSON File '{0}'.".format(jsonFile)
    rows = TD.get_num_rows()
    print rows
    TD.cleanup()


def argparser():
    argparser = ArgumentParser( description = 'PostGreSQL Database operations.' )
    argparser.add_argument('-j',
                           '--jsonFile',
                           help='Full file path to a JSON file containing databse entries.',
                           required = False
                           )
    return argparser

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = argparser().parse_args()
    main(args.jsonFile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> data is not persisting in the database between sessions,

er... do you mean that you have no data between separate invocations of your script?  That's to be expected when you drop all tables:

```
def __init_db(self):
    # ... snip ...
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    #             ^^^^^^^^
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Get rid of that line.  what's it supposed to do if not "drop everything!"

Comment: Thank you so much.  I completely glossed over that - appreciate the help!